# form using AJAX JQUERY PHP not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am unable to load external file while using AJAX jQuery. I want to use jQuery AJAX to pop up form then validate, enter data in MySQL. but starting from a simple AJAX function. Kindly let me know where I am going wrong

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="test_style.css">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">    </script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#ajax-contact-form").submit(function(){
                var str = $(this).serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url:"contact.php",
                    data: str,
                    success:function(result) {
                        $("#div1").html(result);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="contact_form">  
            <form id="ajax-contact-form" name="contact" action=""> 
                <fieldset>
                    <label for="name" id="name_label">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value="" class="text-input"/>  
                    <label class="error" for="name" id="name_error">This field is required.</label>  
                    <input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Message">
                </fieldset>  
            </form>
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

and contact.php file is

```
<?php
echo "Hello";
?>
```

Comment: what error are you getting ? and i see no button element

Comment: Looks like a copy-paste code. Hence you're not able to see the obvious

Comment: there is difference between `<button>` and `<input type="button">` that you can use button for `<input type="button">` its not like random fire

Comment: *"and contact.php file is"* - right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="test_style.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>



<script>
$(function() {  
 $(".button").click(function() {  
    $.ajax({url:"contact.php",success:function(result){
      $("#div1").html(result);
    }});
    return false;
  });
});
</script>


</head>
<body>

<div id="contact_form"> 
<form name="contact" action=""> 
<fieldset>
   <label for="name" id="name_label">Name</label>  
   <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value="" class="text-input" />  
 <label class="error" for="name" id="name_error">This field is required.</label>  

<input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="submit_btn" value="Send" />
</fieldset>  
</form>
</div> 
<div id="div1">
</div> 


</body>
</html>
```

Try that:

What needed to be fixed:

1) You'd duplicated the onReady function,

2) you can use a submit form button, but since it's default action is to submit the form, the result wouldn't have been visible.

3) There was no #div1 for the result to be displayed in.

Hopefully, this has been helpful... Happy Coding!

Comment: this is perfect for me

Answer (score 0):

Try with type `button` type

```
<input type="button" name="submit" class="button" id="submit_btn" value="Send" />
```

And also your both scripts are same use either DOM ready or $(function) like

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".button").click(function(){
          $.ajax({url:"contact.php",success:function(result){
               $("#div1").html(result);
           }});
       });
   });
</script>
```

`button` is your class name so that it will represented like `.button` And create an div with id `div1` at your html page

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#div1").html(result);
```

Use one div which id is **div1** inside your page which you want to show the result.

```
<div id="div1"></div>
```